# How to streamline class initialization within an object based on a parameter type

Tags: c#, generics, design-patterns, coding-style, clean-architecture

Based on a passed parameter containing a type I'm looking for a better way to initialize the class based on that type. Currently I'm "solving" it with a switch statement which is feels quite redundant.

Bad example showing what the functionality is:

```
protected Quest GenerateQuest(QuestConfiguration questConfiguration)
{

    List<QuestObjective> objectives = new();
    foreach ( QuestObjectiveConfiguration questConfigurationObjective in questConfiguration.ObjectiveConfigurations)
    {
        switch (questConfigurationObjective.ObjectiveType)
        {
            case ObjectiveType.Fetch:
                objectives.Add(new ObjectiveFetch(questConfigurationObjective.InternalId));
                break;
            case ObjectiveType.Gather:
                objectives.Add(new ObjectiveGather(questConfigurationObjective.InternalId));
                break;
            case ObjectiveType.Craft:
                objectives.Add(new ObjectiveCraft(questConfigurationObjective.InternalId));
                break;
            case ObjectiveType.Deliver:
                objectives.Add(new ObjectiveDeliver(questConfigurationObjective.InternalId));
                break;
            case ObjectiveType.Combat:
                objectives.Add(new ObjectiveCombatEncounter(questConfigurationObjective.InternalId));
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
    }
    return new Quest(objectives);
}
```

Looked/googled for suiting patterns but I'm having a hard time getting specific results because the related terms are generic and the issue is an edgecase.

Comment: https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/factory-method

Comment: Are you using any kind of dependency injection framework? We're using MEF but I don't want to present a solution if it's not possible at all.

Comment: @SebastianSchumann Unfortunately a third party framework for that won't be an option. Thanks for the suggestion though :)

Comment: @RomanRyzhiy About factories: But then I would have to add factory classes for each type so they can resolve themselves based on the parameter, right? That would eleminate the switch-case - but not really improve the code quality. Or am I missing something about how to use that pattern properly?

Comment: Each implementation will require changing the above switch statement. I would create an interface for the factory that provides the `ObjectiveType` of the supported one. After that I would reflect over all assemblies in `AppDomain` and collect all factories by supported interface and all the method. That is what a dependency injection framework would do. Having this you don't need to change this switch anytime in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `QuestObjective` can be created with just `QuestObjectiveConfiguration`, then I'd consider having the switch statement in a method or extension method of it.

This of course does not get rid of the switch statement but atleast keeps it in one place.

```cs
static class QuestObjectiveConfigurationExtensions
{
    public static QuestObjective ToQuestObjective(
        this QuestObjectiveConfiguration config) => config.ObjectiveType switch
    {
        ObjectiveType.Fetch => new ObjectiveFetch(config.InternalId),
        //rest of your types
        _ => //maybe throw an Exception here
    };
}
```

This shortens your objective creation to

```cs
var objectives = questConfiguration.ObjectiveConfigurations.Select(x => x.ToQuestObjective)
```

You can do the same for `QuestConfiguration` and `Quest` of course and implement a `ToQuest` method.

One option to get rid of the switch statement completely would be to have different types of `QuestObjectiveConfiguration` that implement different methods of `ToQuestObjective`.

Answer (score 2):

With Linq and switch expression you can streamline your method's implementation like this:

```
protected Quest GenerateQuest(QuestConfiguration questConfiguration)
{
    List<QuestObjective> objectives = questConfiguration.ObjectiveConfigurations
    .Select(questConfigurationObjective =>
    {
        var id = questConfigurationObjective.InternalId;
        QuestObjective objective = questConfigurationObjective.ObjectiveType switch
        {
            ObjectiveType.Fetch => new ObjectiveFetch(id),
            ObjectiveType.Gather => new ObjectiveGather(id),
            ObjectiveType.Craft => new ObjectiveCraft(id),
            ObjectiveType.Deliver => new ObjectiveDeliver(id),
            ObjectiveType.Combat => new ObjectiveCombatEncounter(id),
            _ => throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException()
        };
        return objective;
    })
    .ToList();
    
    return new Quest(objectives);
}
```

or you can make it even more concise like this

```
protected Quest GenerateQuest(QuestConfiguration questConfiguration)
    => new Quest(questConfiguration.ObjectiveConfigurations
    .Select(questConfigurationObjective =>
    {
        var id = questConfigurationObjective.InternalId;
        return questConfigurationObjective.ObjectiveType switch
        {
            ObjectiveType.Fetch => new ObjectiveFetch(id),
            ObjectiveType.Gather => new ObjectiveGather(id),
            ObjectiveType.Craft => new ObjectiveCraft(id),
            ObjectiveType.Deliver => new ObjectiveDeliver(id),
            ObjectiveType.Combat => new ObjectiveCombatEncounter(id),
            _ => throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException()
        };
    })
    .ToList());
```

Answer (score 1):

In case your framework version doesn't support  switch expression that Peter Csala suggesed, I have a more traditional approach like:

```
    Quest GenerateQuest(QuestConfiguration questConfiguration)
    {

        List<QuestObjective> objectives = new();
        Dictionary<ObjectiveType, Type> lstActions = new Dictionary<ObjectiveType, Type>();
        lstActions.Add(ObjectiveType.Fetch, typeof(ObjectiveFetch));
        lstActions.Add(ObjectiveType.Gather, typeof(ObjectiveGather));
        lstActions.Add(ObjectiveType.Craft, typeof(ObjectiveCraft));
        lstActions.Add(ObjectiveType.Deliver, typeof(ObjectiveDeliver));
        lstActions.Add(ObjectiveType.Combat, typeof(ObjectiveCombatEncounter));

        foreach (QuestObjectiveConfiguration questConfigurationObjective in questConfiguration.ObjectiveConfigurations)
        {
            if (lstActions.ContainsKey(questConfigurationObjective.ObjectiveType))
                objectives.Add((QuestObjective)Activator.CreateInstance(lstActions[questConfigurationObjective.ObjectiveType], new[] { questConfigurationObjective.InternalId }));
            else
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
            }
        }
        return new Quest(objectives);
    }
```

Comment: At least cache that dictionary in a `static readonly` field. And storing a `Func<int, QuestObjective>` (or whatever the ID type is) will be a lot cheaper than using reflection